# Why does Swarm register "jpa", "undertow" cache containers

Tags: java, infinispan, wildfly-swarm

I am trying to upgrade wildfly swarm version to 2018.2.0.Final (current latest) from 2017.10.0

After run the server with latest version, I got following error on my server log

> ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0026: WildFly Swarm 2018.2.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started (with errors) in                  15832ms - Started 316 of 639 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 444 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

And I checked services via jConsole, Then I found following dump.

> Service
> "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.undertow.activator"
> (class org.wildfly.swarm.infinispan.runtime.CacheActivator$1) mode
> ACTIVE state DOWN (PROBLEM) (parent: jboss.as) (dependencies:
> org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.undertow)
> (has unavailable dependency)
>
> Service "org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.jpa.activator"
> (class org.wildfly.swarm.infinispan.runtime.CacheActivator$1) mode
> ACTIVE state DOWN (PROBLEM) (parent: jboss.as) (dependencies:
> org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-container-configuration.jpa)
> (has unavailable dependency)

I added infinispan cache containers by self

- server
- web
- ejb
- hibernate

Seems like they registered by InfinispanCustomizer#undertowActivator and  InfinispanCustomizer#jpaActivator
They added since 2017.12.0

InfinispanCustomizer.java

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public ServiceActivator undertowActivator() {
    return new CacheActivator("undertow");
}

@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public ServiceActivator jpaActivator() {
    return new CacheActivator("jpa");
}
```

I have no idea What should I do to remove error with latest Wildfly Swarm?

Comment: Please raise an issue at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM as clearly we missed a dependency for one of those services.

Comment: I created issue on https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM-1845?page=com.docminer.jira.issue-links%3Acom.kintosoft.jira.links.tab-panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed on wildfly swarm version 2018.4.1
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/THORN-1845